# Trying to copy objects across scenes but it duplicates my scenes instead (BGE)

Tags: game-engine, scene

I am ctrl+c some objects (planes and texts) from one scene to paste (ctrl+v) into another scene. But in the other scene (the one I want to copy them to) they do not show up and it duplicates all my scenes (see image below). I am in BGE and the texts have logic bricks too if that matters. What should I do?
[image: Duplicated scenes]
I have no idea what the L means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"L" means the data is linked. Typically it is linked from another file.

I never used <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>. Maybe because i usually do not copy objects between different scenes (but move them). I tried it and it worked as expected. So I cannot confirm the behavior you describe.

#### Another way to copy an object:

To get objects from one scene to another I suggest:

- select the objects
- link to the target scene <kbd>ctrl+L</kbd> Objects to Scene .../target scene
- switch to the target scene
- make single user <kbd>U</kbd> (Attention: the name will change)

Comment: works perfectly. Good to know.